# Chain rule for $\ln(-f(\pmb{x}))$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am trying to figure out how to calculate, for a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the second and higher order derivatives of $\ln(-f(\pmb{x}))$. I am not sure the notation, but I would guess this is written like this:

$$\frac{d^{2}}{d\pmb{x}^{2}} \ln(-f(\pmb{x})).$$

The wikipedia entry on vector valued functions mentions multiple different types of derivatives and a set of notes I found online refers to Hilbert spaces, Metric matrices and other notions which I think are too general for what I want to calculate (and they are also at a level of mathematics beyond what I understand).

So far, I can convince myself that the first derivative I want should look something like

$$\frac{d}{d\pmb{x}}\ln(-f(\pmb{x})) = -\frac{\nabla f(\pmb{x})}{f(\pmb{x})}$$

but then I get pretty stuck for the second derivative. I tried to write it out like this

$$\frac{d}{d \pmb{x}}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{f(\pmb{x}_{i})}{f(\pmb{x})}$$

however, I can't imagine what kind of chain rule I could apply here.

I should point out that I have yet to take a course in vector calculus, but I have a textbook which covers some and none of the information even seems related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to suggest that you restrict your attention to the partial derivatives, i.e., how $\ln(f(x_1, \ldots, x_n))$ varies when you vary $x_i$. For this, you can think of this as a one-variable calculus problem, and the result is
$$
\frac{d\ln(f(\mathbf x))}{dx_i} = \frac{1}{f(\mathbf x)} \frac{df(\mathbf x)}{dx_i}.
$$

By long tradition, this derivative with respect to one of the variables is denoted by rounded "d" rather than the ordinary "d", so we write instead

$$
\frac{\partial \ln(f(\mathbf x))}{\partial x_i} = \frac{1}{f(\mathbf x)} \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_i}.
$$

Now you can repeat that process, and ask what is the derivative of that expression with respect to a variable $x_j$.

The results is

$$
\frac{\partial^2 \ln(f(\mathbf x))}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} 
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left(\frac{1}{f(\mathbf x)} \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_i} \right) \\
= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left(\frac{1}{f(\mathbf x)} \right) \left( \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_i} \right) + \left(\frac{1}{f(\mathbf x)} \right) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left( \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_i} \right) \\
= \frac{-\frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_j}}{f^2(\mathbf x)} \left( \frac{\partial f(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_i} \right) + \left(\frac{1}{f(\mathbf x)} \right) \left( \frac{\partial^2 f(\mathbf x)}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \right) =
$$

For each $i$ and $j$, that's a number; those numbers, arranged in a matrix, are the second derivative. The matrix is also called the "Hessian" of $f$, and properly speaking, I should say that the Hessian is the representation of the second derivative -- which is a bilinear form -- with respect to the standard basis, but I think that's probably too much information just now.

Let me apply that to 
$$
f(x, y) = x \sin y
$$
The partials with respect to $x$ and $y$ are (in a notation where we use subscripts to denote derivatives)

$$
f_x(x, y) = \sin y \\
f_y(x, y) = x\cos y ||. 
$$

The second partials are
$$
f_{xx}(x, y) = 0 \\
f_{xy}(x, y) = \cos y \\
f_{yx}(x, y) = \cos y \\
f_{yy}(x, y) = -x\sin y 
$$
and the Hessian is
$$
H(f)(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \cos y \\ \cos y  &\ -x \sin y\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now if you degine $g(x, y) = \ln(f(x, y))$, you can do the same computation for $g$ and find its hessian, and see whether it matches what I wrote that it should be above.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I am having a little bit of trouble following the indices though. It seems like I can rewrite your equation into $\frac{-\frac{f(\pmb{x})}{x_{j}}}{f^{2}(\pmb{x})} \left(\frac{\partial f(\pmb{x})}{\partial x_{i}} \right) + \frac{1}{f(\pmb{x})} H(f)(\pmb{x})$, but does the first term simplify? I don't see any nice way of arranging it.

Comment: This is the $ij$-element of the matrix, so your $H(f)$ should be $H(f)_{ij}$. Also: you lost two partials in the first fraction. If we say that the column-vector of partial derivatives is the gradient, then you can write this mess (for all $i$ and $j$ together) as $$H(g) = \frac{1}{f^2(x)} (\nabla f(x)) (\nabla f(x))^t + \frac{1}{f(x)} H(f)(x)$$, i.e., as involving an outer product of the gradient with itself, and the hessian of $f$.

Comment: I think I finally worked out all the details and understand now. Thank you again.